# Headset buttons controls

Tags: android, android-broadcast, audio-player, android-music-player

Now what is happening is it is also controlling other music players. If i have a default music player after starting that if i start playing using my music player and then i press play/pause button in headset it controls default music player.
i have implemented a heaset broadcastreceiver like this,

```
            switch (keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK:
                    Log.d("TAG", "TAG: KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK");
                    if (MusicService.isPlaying()) {
                        MusicService.player.pause();
                    } else {
                        MusicService.player.start();
                    }
                    new MusicService().showNotification();
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                    Log.d("TAG", "TAG: KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY");
                    if (MusicService.isPlaying()) {
                        MusicService.player.pause();
                    } else {
                        MusicService.player.start();
                    }
                    new MusicService().showNotification();
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                    Log.d("TAG", "TAG: KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                    Log.d("TAG", "TAG: KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT");
                    if (MusicService.player.isPlaying()) {
                        MusicService.player.stop();
                    }
                    if (MusicService.songPosn < (MusicService.song.size() - 1)) {
                        MusicService.songPosn = MusicService.songPosn + 1;
                        if (SingleInstance.getInstance().getIndexCount()>= 1)
                            SingleInstance.getInstance().setIndexCount(SingleInstance.getInstance().getIndexCount()-1);
                    } else {
                        // play first song
                        MusicService.songPosn = 0;
                    }
                    new MusicService().playSong(true);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                    Log.d("TAG", "TAG: KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS");
                    if (MusicService.player.isPlaying()) {
                        MusicService.player.stop();
                    }
                    if (MusicService.songPosn > 0) {
                        MusicService.songPosn = MusicService.songPosn - 1;
                    } else {
                        // play last song
                        MusicService.songPosn = MusicService.song.size() - 1;
                    }
                    new MusicService().playSong(true);
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the hedsethook event in a activity follow the below code :

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK:
                // Headset key detected
               // Do your stuff here
                return true;// To let the os know that the event is consumed here 
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Make sure to returt true to consume the event .To get it done in a service use BroadCast receiver as follows:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);//"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"
MediaButtonIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
filter.setPriority(1000); //Sets receiver priority
registerReceiver(r, filter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @ADM. First part of your answer was useful for me. But i want to gain audio focus to my music player when i press play/pause button from headset.